# don't submit form if form is empty

Tags: php, database, jquery, textfield, formfield

this is my first post and i'm rather new to php + ajax.

I have most of my coding set up only problem now is that when i press the submit button an notification shows up that only should show up when the text fields aren't empty.

This is my code:

```
<head><script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#ContactForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for subscribing to SHCA"); 
            document.forms["ContactForm"].reset();
        }); 
    }); 

</script> </head>
```

followed by some php coding:

```
<?php
        if(strlen($_POST['name']) > 0 AND strlen($_POST['email']) > 0)
        {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
         $hostdb = '';
         $namedb = '';
         $userdb = '';
         $passdb = '';

        $conn = mysqli_connect($hostdb , $userdb, $passdb ,$namedb);


        $sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[email]')";



        if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
        {
        die('Error: ' .mysql_error($conn));
        }

        if (!mysqli_ping($conn)) {
echo 'Lost connection, exiting after query #1';
exit;
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}}
else
{
```

?>

```
        <form id="ContactForm" action="" method="post">

                    <label for="author">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required input_field float_r" />
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate-email required input_field float_r" />

                    <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" />
        </form>
        <?php } ?>
```

hope anyone here is able to tell me what i should do to only show the "Thank you for subscribing to SHCA" message when the textfields aren't empty

final anwser Dereck forgot the '' in the objects so shout out to dereck for helping me!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
    $('#ContactForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
        if( !$('#name').val()) {
             alert("please enter your name");
        }
        if(!$('#email').val()) {
            alert("plese enter your email adress");
            }
        else{
            alert("Thank you for subscribing to SHCA"); 
        }

        document.forms["ContactForm"].reset();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: what i'm curious about is, am i protected against sql injection and if not what do i need to do to protect myself from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it without having to do a refresh

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
    $('#ContactForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
        if( !$(#name).val() || !$(#email).val()) {
             //don't display
        }else{
            alert("Thank you for subscribing to SHCA"); 
        }

        document.forms["ContactForm"].reset();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: do you happen to know how i could only check for 1 character in ajax?
so just like you showed me above and then i want to check if there is an @ in the email field

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the contents of the fields before submitting to the server, a simple script method can check before you submit. If the fields are empty then display an error messge and don't submit the form.

```
function SubmitDetails()
{
    if(window.ContactForm.name.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter a name");
        return;
    }if(window.ContactForm.email.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter an email" );
        return;
    }

    window.ContactForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: and where should i implant that?
would i need to take the ajax out or is this an addition to it

Comment: This should be placed in the client side, when the submit button is pressed, your script will intercept before sending to the server. onclick='SubmitDetails();'

Comment: i see what you mean now, but the problem with this is that when you submit the page goes back to the top, thats why i inplanted the ajax script this prevents it from going back to the top as long as it is used to submit the form

Comment: So are you trying to submit and add the details without actually submitting the page? You don't want to refresh?

Comment: nope don't want it to refresh, how it is now works flawless except that i get the "You're now subscribed" message even when you just leave the fields blank

Comment: Just before you display the alert message, check the contents of the input fields, if they are empty don't display the message          if( !$(#email).val() ) {
          //don't display
}else alert("message");